# Using choices in a field in django models

Tags: django, django-models

This is my models.py:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer=models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    paymentstatus = ( 
    ("Payment Successful", "Payment Successful"), 
    ("Payment Pending", "Payment Pending"), 
    ("Payment Failed", "Payment Failed"),  
    )
    status=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,null=True,choices=paymentstatus)
```

In my views.py I have a view which checks whether the payment has been completed or not in that I want to set the payment status (for example if payment is completed then I want to set status as Payment Successful). This is how I tried it:

```
if response_dict['RESPCODE'] == '01':
            order.status=Payment Successful
            order.save()
            print('order successful')
```

But this is not working. Also once done I want to have it on a html template so would iterating like {{order.status}} would be correct? If not then how do I access it in my template.

Comment: Can you include your error trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass it as a string:

```
if response_dict['RESPCODE'] == '01':
            order.status=Payment Successful
            order.save()
            print('order successful')
```

and you can simply access it by using `{% for ord in orders %}  {{ord.status}}` where you need to pass orders as context